# Suitalbe ISO for Virtual box

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox

I fed up using emulator because it is very slow and takes 30 min to start and run the application.

Hence decided to use virtual box and installed on my laptop now for android images I am using this [link](http://www.android-x86.org/download)

Now I am confused on what to download and use because the one I have downloaded is the image of Tablet but I need image of a mobile phone.

Can anyone suggest me which ISO need to be downloaded for a mobile application develpment.

Thanks
Siva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual box will also very slow. I would suggest you buy a cheap real device.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gaurav thats a last option for me as I can't to real devices for all versions(Tables, Different sized mobile phones) so I am searchihg for something in virtual box

Comment: Try android-x86-4.2-20121225.iso if your computer is 64 bit

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I will try and mark your post as "Answered"

Comment: Not sure what your app is doing, but generally speaking, you don't need to test for every screen size on EVERY change you do. Like I have two devices, Nexus S and Nexus 7, both pretty much for development. And if I need to test something to make sure it works in an odd situation, then I would run a virtual. Just a thought, maybe you don't actually need all possible devices throughout the developments.